# Is it possible to Web Request from a Raspberry Pi Google Assistant to a socket (http://192.168.X.X:8000) using IFTTT (WebHooks)?

Tags: sockets, httpwebrequest, raspberry-pi3, webhooks, ifttt

This is a huge project that my group is working on right now. We are very inexperienced with IoTs and Web stuffs.

First, we created an android app and with it, we're sending a message to the socket with port 8000 (192.168.X.X:8000) with a press of a button. The messages being sent are color names (Green, Red, Blue, etc) and our raspberry pi is running a script that could decode this color names, control the GPIO, and light up a whole LED Strip depending on the color sent. We are successful in this portion.

In addition, we managed to successfully install Google Assistant into Raspberry Pi. Now, we're planning to use IFTTT (If Google Assistant Then WebHooks) to make custom commands for our Google Assistant. We also managed to run the LEDStrip script and the Google Assistant script together on Raspberry Pi with no issues at all.

Now the problem that we're facing is sending a message to the socket.
Example: "Ok Google, Green Light Please" will send a message "Green" to the socket and the LEDStrip script will just receive it normally like how it receives messages from the android app.

Is it possible to do this? I've been researching a lot about POSTing Web Requests to http://192.168.X.X:8000 using IFTTT; and even tried the Google Advanced REST Client to do it manually but I'm just not successful at all. It says the http://192.168.X.X:8000 is not a valid URL or can't be accessed.

ISSUES ENCOUNTERED SO FAR:

1. Directly controlling GPIOs with Google Assistant on Raspberry pi by customizing hotword.py isn't successful for us at all because we can't import the neopixel library since the Google Assistant runs in virtual environment (env).

Thanks. Hope someone would be able to help us. We accept any recommendations on how to make our project successful.

Comment: You need to expose your PI on a public IP address ... or NAT https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_addresses

Comment: Hi @KelvinLai. thanks for the info. I'll give it a try